# How to show my function exception error in qerromessagebox

Tags: python, sqlite, error-handling, pyqt5

I have this program which is used to get a input from barcode reader and save it to SQLite  database. For the GUI part i use PYQT5 and used QThread and QObject for Multithreading What i want to use it that if there are any error occured when inserting to table i need to show the error message in the window via QerrorMessage.

This is my class for the Database connection and inserting data

```
import sqlite3


class DBConnector():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('inventory.db',timeout=10,check_same_thread=False)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.init()

    
    def init(self):
        self.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;')
        self.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS component(componentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,component_name TEXT NOT NULL, UNIQUE(component_name));')
        self.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS componentdata(componentdataID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,serial TEXT NOT NULL,description TEXT NOT NULL,componentID INTEGER NOT NULL,FOREIGN KEY(componentID) REFERENCES component(componentID),UNIQUE(serial));')
        self.execute('INSERT INTO component(component_name) VALUES("RAM"),("HARD DRIVE"),("POWER SUPPLY UNIT"),("MOTHERBOARD"),("PROCCESOR");')

            
    

        
        
    def execute(self,query):
        result = None
        try:
            result=self.cursor.execute(query)
           
            self.conn.commit()
        except sqlite3.Error as err:
            print(err)
        if result:
            return result
```

This is the Qthread class i implemented for mulithreading

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    QThread,
    QObject,
    pyqtSignal,
    pyqtSlot
)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QErrorMessage


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    error = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal(object)
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    
class Worker(QThread):
    def __init__(self,fn,**kwargs):
        super(Worker,self).__init__()
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()
        self.fn = fn
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        try:
            self.fn(**self.kwargs)
        except:
           print('error occured')
```

And this is the pyqt5 code for my window

```
class SubWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,windowtitle):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle(windowtitle)

        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        
       
        self.serial = myLayout(QHBoxLayout,'Serial Number')
        self.description = myLayout(QHBoxLayout,'Description')  
        self.cb = QComboBox(self)

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.cb)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.serial.layout)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.description.layout)
        
        self.dbc = DBConnector()
        self.combo = self.dbc.execute("select * from component")
        self.combolist = self.combo.fetchall()
        for i in self.combolist:
            self.cb.addItem(i[1])
        self.savebutton = QPushButton("SAVE")
        self.savebutton.clicked.connect(self.save)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.savebutton)
        
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)        
        


    def save(self):
            ComponentID = self.dbc.execute("select componentID from component where component_name='%s'"%(self.cb.currentText())).fetchall()
            ComponentID = ComponentID[0][0]
            self.kwargs = {'query':"insert into componentdata(serial,description,componentID) values('%s','%s',%d)"%(self.serial.layoutLine.text(),self.description.layoutLine.text(),ComponentID)}
            self.worker = Worker(self.dbc.execute,**self.kwargs)
            # self.worker.finished.connect(self.succesmsg)
            self.worker.finished.connect(self.close)
            self.worker.start()

        
    def succesmsg(self):
       self.msg= QMessageBox()
       self.msg.setWindowTitle("Status")
       self.msg.setText("DONE")
       self.msg.show()
```

Comment: You already created a signal called `error`, but you're not using it. All you need to do is emit that signal with the appropriate error messages inside the except-block. Then you can connect the signal to a slot in the ui where the messages can be displayed.

Comment: how can emit the error and print the exception

Answer (score 0):

Here Try This!

```
def show_error(self):
    error = "This is an Awesome Error :)"
    em = QErrorMessage()
    em.showMessage(error)
```

Comment: I want to show the sqlite error in `QErrorMessage` using and showing the error if exception error happened my DBConnector Class. How to do that?